# QT Linguist phrasebook from .TS file

Tags: qt, translation

I'm working on a Translation with QT Linguist. Several words have multiple entries so I would like to Reuse the words already translated to "batch translate" the rest of the files. Batch Translation is only possible with a phrasebook. Is there a way to automatically put all the words of a .ts file into a phrasebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small C#/Mono program to make a QT phrasebook out of a .ts file:

https://github.com/galgalesh/PhrasebookMaker